# Kubernetes job waiting status

Tags: kubernetes, timeout, jobs

I have a job in kubernetes cluster that is run through cron in jenkins. As the cluster sometimes does not have enough resources to start a pod, it is in waiting status until it finds free resources. How can I stop/kill job and the waiting pod if certain time has passed.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't do that, because a controller or watcher for Job/ cronjob object is always taking care to spawn the desired number of replicas mentioned by you in the specs.

There is one option that you can add to your spec file and configure it in such a way that if that much time against the scheduled time gets passed then the pod won't be created.

You can always add **startingDeadlineSeconds** in the cronjob spec, now if the schedule is missed or nodes were down then pod won't be spawned here.

For more information you can refer to following [link](https://medium.com/@hengfeng/what-does-kubernetes-cronjobs-startingdeadlineseconds-exactly-mean-cc2117f9795f), hope this helps.